# Correctly using geom_alpha_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data such as the iris data set.

```
data(iris)
ggplot(data=iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color = Species, fill = Species)) + geom_point()
```

I color and fill the data in by `Species`. How can I correctly use `geom_alpha_manual()` to set `setosa` to `alpha = 0.2`,  `versicolor` to `alpha = 0.5` and `virginica` to `alpha = 0.8`?

Alternatively, how can I also use the `scale_shape_manual(..., values)` to set the different shapes based on the `Species`?

I can use `scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "green")` and `scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "green")` but I am a little unsure on how to set the different alpha values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to map `Species` to `alpha` and `shape` too.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris,
       aes(
         x = Sepal.Length,
         y = Sepal.Width,
         color = Species,
         fill = Species,
         shape = Species,
         alpha = Species
       )) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "green"), 
                    aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(setosa = .2,
                                versicolor = .5,
                                virginica = .8)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 1:3) +
  # optional guide adjustments below
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1,
                                                  size = 3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have added some additional data. I cannot seem to get the `alpha` working correctly for both my my `classes`. The `shape` of the data is not so important.

Comment: Second question: Using `scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkred", "blue"),
                    aesthetics = c("color", "fill"))` for example is this a "replacement" to using `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_color_manual` twice, as I was using in my original post?

Comment: @user113156 Regarding your first comment: Maybe better ask a new question. It code works for `iris` data.
Second comment: yes.

Comment: Is it just me or do the blue dots of Species = setosa look as they have a different alpha-value? I would have expected that they are all the same (.2)?